# OPENVAS: error while loading shared libraries: libopenvas_nasl.so.21

Tags: openvas

After installing openvas-scanner with the command "sudo apt-get install openvas"
I get an error when i try to lauch it with the command "openvas"

This is the error.

openvas: error while loading shared libraries: libopenvas_nasl.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

My computer.
OS: Debian Linux Ubuntu 22.04

[the commands i typed are here in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp7tT.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su], [unix.se], or [ubuntu.se].